# Open problems in Proof theory and Logic

Tags: logic, proof-theory, open-problem

There are numerous questions in the same form: "What are some open problems in mathematical logic". So for this we know:
Shelahs "Logical Dreams"
[Logical Dreams](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211398)

Friedmans "102 Problems in mathematical logic"
[Friedman's list](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2271891)

my first question is:
Is there somewhere an updated list of these problems (which of them are solved)?

and now a very specific question:
Are there any open problems in classical proof theory or unsolved conjectures? If so, where do I find them?

Comment: Wikipedia is usually a good idea for such lists , and they are usually soon updated , if there are new results.